# Quando clicar no botao ir para fazer o cadastro

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, sou iniciante e gostaria de saber como redireciono o usuario a uma pagina de cadastro quando ele apertar o botao de se inscrver ou logar no site.

```
<body>
<header class="menu-principal">
    <main>

    </main>

</header>
<main class="coluna menu-urls">
<div class="parte-1">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="">PRATIQUE</a></li>
            <li><a href="">SOBRE NÓS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CONTATO</a></li>
            <li><a href="">AJUDA</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inscrever">
    
    <input class="bnt st-button" type="button" value ="Inscrever-se"/>
    <input class="bnt es-button" type="button" value ="Entrar">
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: `window.location.href = 'link-da-pagina-de-cadastro'`

Comment: <input class="bnt st-button" type="button" value ="Inscrever-se" onclick="window.location='https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions';" />

Comment: O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Veja como marcar resposta como aceita https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Comment: Comece aqui para ter uma visão rápida do site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Algumas formas

1 -  Redirecionando com window.location

obs: `location` é sinonimo de `location.href`

```
<input class="bnt st-button" type="button" value ="Inscrever-se" onclick="window.location='https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions';" />
```

```css
.bnt {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #969696;
}

.bnt:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #969696;
  transition: color 0.2s 0.05s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.2s 0.05s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input class="bnt st-button" type="button" value ="Inscrever-se" onclick="window.location='https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions';" /> 

<input class="bnt st-button" type="button" value ="Entrar" onclick="window.location='https://pt.stackoverflow.com/';" />
```

2 - função javascript

```js
function novaPagina(num) {
var url=new Array();
url[0]="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions";
url[1]="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/";
window.location=url[num];
}
```

```html
<input class="bnt st-button" type="button" value ="Inscrever-se" onclick="novaPagina(0)"> 
    
<input class="bnt es-button" type="button" value ="Entrar" onclick="novaPagina(1)">
```

Comment: Como eu faço para quando apertar o botao de inscrever-se e login vá para uma pagina local do meu computador onde eu fiz a tela de cadastro? por exemplo, eu posso colocar o onclick="window.location.href = '#'"

Comment: @olamundo97, esse # não vai redirecionar pra lugar nenhum. A navegação no comutador é exatamente como se estivesse no servidor.  Você vai até a pasta  onde está o arquivo, duplo clique nele ai deve abrir com endereço tipo  file:///C:/Users/Fulano/Documents/teste/pagina_com_botao.html e clicando no botão abre a pagina login ou inscrever-se. Se os dois arquivos estiverem na mesma pasta então no botão basta, por exemplo,  onclick="window.location='login.html';"

Comment: nossa, eu consegui!!! muitoo obg :)

Answer (score -1):

Opa!

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas: Usando a tag  (link) do html:

Exemplo:

```html
<a href="www.seulink.com.br/inscrever-se">
  <input class="bnt st-button" type="button" value ="Inscrever-se"/>
</a>
```

Se é somente redirecionar para outra página essas é a forma mais simples.

Mas pode fazer também com outras linguagens de programação como Javascript ou PHP.

Seria isso?

Comment: Amigo o seu HTML não é valido! **Não é permitido usa um Input dentro de um A** https://prnt.sc/tot7os se vc quiser testar por conta própria é só coloar seu HTML aqui https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea Use um `button` ou estilize com CSS para o Link ficar como o estilo do button

Comment: Pode não ser permitido mas eu pergunto, funciona? em todos os navegadores e versões? ha bom, certo, papai não deixa

Comment: Rapaz... eu voei nesse resposta... usar window.location é a melhor solução.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo varrer sujeira para baixo do tapete resolve? Beber água da privada mata a sede? Eu não sei se vc trabalha validando sou código, ou com algum validador automático na compilação etc, mas nesse caso em particular existem vários workarounds totalmente válidos... mas cada um mantêm o nível de qualidade que consegue.

Comment: @hugocsl, Depende do contexto, se você estiver em uma guerra aposto que vai beber água da privada na ausência de outra fonte. Esse papo de não válido pra mim  é blablabla. FUNCIONA, sim, PT saudações!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo na guerra esse é o tipo de soldado que morre no primeiro combate ou que atira no próprio pé. Abs

Comment: @hugocsl, filosofia barata, isso é o que vc diz. Vai ver se estou lá na esquina.